# How to set/Reset the previously selected multi Select option in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application, User selects different teams & based on teams, he selects some players. Now user is updating his team choice. Since he has selected "Royal Challengers" team & some players . he is not allowed to do so, once he remove players from "Royal challengers" or any team then only he will be allowed to update his team choice. 
So for that, before updating his team(before onChange()), i am checking the players count & if players count is greater than 1, then show a pop up to inform him to remove players. 
Now on clicking of "OK" , he should see the previous selected team names.

here is my code.

```
const prevSelected = $('#teams :selected').map(function() {return $.trim($(this).text())}).get();
//prev selected value is : Kolkata,Delhi,Royal Challengers
$('#teams').on('change', function(){ 
    const selected = $('#teams :selected').map(function() {return $.trim($(this).text())}).get();
    var count = $("#teamName").find("br").length;           

    if(count >= 1){         
        //here user is updating his team. 
        if( selected.indexOf('Royal Challengers') == -1){
            alert("There are currently "+count+" players with "+ teamName +". These players must be migrated to a different teams before you can remove the Team 'Royal Challengers' from this Tournament");
            // code to get the previous selected players
            return;
        } 
    }

}
```

**I tried this But didn't work -**

```
 if(count >= 1){
    //user changes, if the new selected option contains other than "Royal Challengers" then display the pop up & clicking on "OK" display the previous selected teams.                   
    if( selected.indexOf('Royal Challengers') == -1){                       
       alert("-------");
       $(prevSelected).prop('selected', true);
    }
 }
```

**Please help.**

Comment: please elaborate. Not able to understand what is the issue

Comment: thank you @AnoopLL....Elaborated. Kindly have a look.

Comment: You can use JStorage to store the players and whenever he clicks ok display the players in the jstorage

Answer (score 0):

this solves my issue -

```
for(var i=0;i<selected.length;i++){
    if(selected[i]!=''){
        $('option:contains('+selected[i]+')').prop('selected', false);
    }
}

for(var i=0;i<prevSelected.length;i++){
    if(prevSelected[i]!=''){
        $('option:contains('+prevSelected[i]+')').prop('selected', true);       
    }
}
```